# php cli segmentation fault (core dumped) problem

Tags: php, docker, segmentation-fault

I have a php-apache docker container with a php script to generate some data, when I run this script in cli mode it start running and after some time it crashes with message "segmentation fault (core dumped)", knowing that this script and the container run on other hosts without problem..
How to fix this problem?
any help would be appreciated...

Comment: There's no way anybody can help you given this amount of information. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: so just to be clear, the segmentation fult is happening at the application level!, you are not getting your docker crashed at all?

What is that script doing? the program then is leaving a core file around, how big is it? can you open it with gdb? the bt command will tell you the fault

Comment: yes, the script crashes not the container, and what baffles me is that it works on another similar machine server without problem...

Comment: Try to go the gdb {core file}, then use bt and paste the output.

Comment: BTW, if this runs on other machines and not on this one, the issue is most likely to be data, so the program is loading something unexpected.